# can't get webpage content properly

Tags: php

I am trying to get the content of a webpage to extract rss links. I've written the following code. It gets the webpage content but it removes some parts of the content that I need!

```
<?php
function getUrl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    $timeout = 5; // set to zero for no timeout 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    print_r($ch); 
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $file_contents;
}

echo getUrl("http://www.journaltocs.ac.uk/index.php?action=browse&subAction=pub&publisherID=10&local_page=1&sorType=DESC&sorCol=2&pageb=1");

?>
```

This is what I need from the above mentioned url that contains a link with title="Journal TOC RSS feeds".

```
<p style="text-align:left;">Publisher: <b><a href="http://www.law.ed.ac.uk/ahrc" target="_blank"><b>AHRC Research Centre</b></a> <a href="http://www.law.ed.ac.uk/ahrc" title="Publisher Homepage" target="_blank"><img src="images/link_external.png" border="0" style="vertical-align:middle;margin:0;"></a> &nbsp; </b> (Total: 1 journals)</p><table style="width:100%"><tr valign="top"><td style="width:25px;"><input type="checkbox" class="nobox" id="search_result_journal_19827xxx19039" name="journal[]" onclick="process_journal_tick(this, 'my_tocs');" value="19827xxx19039"  /></td><td><a href="index.php?action=browse&subAction=pub&publisherID=10&journalID=19827&pageb=1&userQueryID=&sort=&local_page=1&sorType=DESC&sorCol=2">SCRIPTed - A J. of Law, Technology & Society</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="http://www.law.ed.ac.uk/ahrc/script-ed/index.asp" title="Journal Homepage" target="_blank"><img src="images/layout_elements/triangle.png" border="0" style="vertical-align:middle;margin:0;"></a> <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/Script-ed?format=xml" title="Journal TOC RSS feeds" target="_blank"><img src="images/icon_feed.jpg" border="0" style="vertical-align:middle;margin:0;"></a> <img src="images/icon_oa.jpg" border="0" style="vertical-align:middle;margin:0;" title="Open Access" alt="Open Access">  &nbsp; <span style="color:#A8A8A8;">(<span style="color:#808080;">Followers:</span> 7)</span> </td>
</tr></table>
```

But what I get from the code is:

```
<p style="text-align:left;">Publisher: <b><a href="http://www.law.ed.ac.uk/ahrc" target="_blank"><b>AHRC Research Centre</b></a> <a href="http://www.law.ed.ac.uk/ahrc" title="Publisher Homepage" target="_blank"><img src="images/link_external.png" border="0" style="vertical-align:middle;margin:0;"></a> &nbsp; </b> (Total: 1 journals)</p><table style="width:100%"><tr valign="top"><td style="width:25px;"><input type="checkbox" class="nobox" id="search_result_journal_19827xxx0" name="journal[]" onclick="process_journal_tick(this, 'my_tocs');" value="19827xxx0"  /></td><td><a href="index.php?action=browse&subAction=pub&publisherID=10&journalID=19827&pageb=1&userQueryID=&sort=&local_page=1&sorType=DESC&sorCol=2">SCRIPTed - A J. of Law, Technology & Society</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="http://www.law.ed.ac.uk/ahrc/script-ed/index.asp" title="Journal Homepage" target="_blank"><img src="images/layout_elements/triangle.png" border="0" style="vertical-align:middle;margin:0;"></a>  <img src="images/icon_oa.jpg" border="0" style="vertical-align:middle;margin:0;" title="Open Access" alt="Open Access">  &nbsp; <span style="color:#A8A8A8;">(<span style="color:#808080;">Followers:</span> 7)</span> </td>
</tr></table>
```

As you see the link with title="Journal TOC RSS feeds" has been removed!!!!

I've already checked with file_get_content($url) but it didn't help!!!
Would you please help me to resolve it?! I have no idea what the problem is!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you have to set an user agent.

Comment: I added  but didn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function SendCurl($url, $post, $post_data, $user_agent, $cookies){  

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    if($user_agent)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    if($post) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    }

    if($cookies) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
    } else {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
    }

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $http = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    return array($http, $response);
}

$login_email = "your email";
$login_password = "your password";
$login_url = "http://www.journaltocs.ac.uk/?action=login";
$user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5'; //optional
$login_data = array(
    'f_user'=>$login_email,
    'f_pass'=>$login_password
);

$webpage_url = "http://www.journaltocs.ac.uk/index.php?action=browse&subAction=pub&publisherID=10&local_page=1&sorType=DESC&sorCol=2&pageb=1";

try{
    //login first and save cookies
    $response = SendCurl($login_url,true,$login_data,$user_agent);
    //if login failed
    if( strpos($response[1],"Username or Password is incorrect") )
        throw new Exception("Username or Password is incorrect");

    //start fetch webpage
    $response = SendCurl($webpage_url,false,false,$user_agent,"cookies.txt");
    if( strpos($response[1],"Journal TOC RSS feeds") )
        die("Journal TOC RSS feeds button is found");

}catch(Exception $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

RSS Feeds icon only shows up **when you logined**,

So You need to login before you fetch the webpage content

Comment: No change yet. I run this script in my Debian server command line if it matters!

Comment: This is the output: `<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=2XrPVLO8CtOy8weVz4CQAQ">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>`

Comment: Wow! It works! :)))) Thank you very much! You have been such a great help to me Parfait! I’ve just understood that rss links are just available to logged in users. I have to login before sending request for the contents in my php code! Since I am always logged in to this website I forgot this obvious point! Thank you very very much for taking time!
Ps: For the first login you forgot to put the quotations for the last parameter, it must be like `$response = SendCurl($login_url,true,$login_data,$user_agent,’’);`